# Installing spatialite-gui using ubuntugis

Tags: spatialite, ubuntugis

I am unable to install spatialite-gui using the ubuntugis unstable ppa. There appears to be a conflict between the GEOs libraries required by QGIS, which I installed first successfully (GEOS 3.5.0 automatically installed as a dependency), and the GEOS libraries required by spatialite-gui. Here is the error I receive when trying to install spatialite-gui:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 spatialite-gui : Depends: libgeos-c1 (>= 3.4.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I try to install libgeos-c1, I see that this install would remove my QGIS install. Is is possible to have both QGIS and spatialite-gui installed from ubuntugis ppa, either w/ GEOS 3.5 or another version?

Edit: 
Ubuntu 14.04.4
QGIS 2.16.0

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? which version of QGIS?

Comment: I can verify the prob on ubuntu 14.04. I guess that spatialite_gui will need to be repackaged with the newer geos and gdal libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maintainer of ubuntugis has been rebuilding all packages related to gdal and the new geos libraries. Spatialite_gui should be available soon. Here's his message:

> Thanks for reporting this issue, I've rebuilt spatialite-gui for the
>   geos  transition in ubuntugis-unstable and uploaded the new revision 
>   (1.7.1-5~trusty3) to my staging PPA.
>
> I've copied the packages to the ubuntugis-unstable PPA after the
>   builds  were confirmed successful in my staging PPA.